# Facebook API - Run javascript after user has logged in

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

at the minute I have this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>    
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ appId:'188492754501683', cookie:true, status:true, xfbml:true }); 
  };
</script> 
<fb:login-button perms="email">
  login with Facebook
</fb:login-button>
```

I want to run some code to pull the email aswell, say this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(res) { if (res != null) { alert(res.email); } } );
```

When I added this under the call to FB.init(), it was run as soon as the window loaded, which is understandable but not what I wanted.

I want the code to run AFTER the user has clicked the Login With Facebook button, and then successfully logged in, etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, I've searched google but can't seem to find anything :/

Thanks in advance, Tom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the events for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title>Facebook Test</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>        
        <script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        // user logedin
    });
};
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

</script>

        <fb:login-button perms="email">
            Login with Facebook
        </fb:login-button>        
</body>
</html>
```

see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ for more events you could subscribe to.

updated with full example

Comment: Hi, I tried this but when I add the call to FB.api() inside the block, it still runs when the page loads. My full code is at: http://pastebin.com/2rr9Q94d Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it this way and it stops the code from running when the window loads but it doesn't respond either when the button is clicked (the alert window doesn't pop up) :S